# meminfoの見方について教えてください

Tags: linux, centos

サーバ上のメモリ使用率を計算したく、meminfoの値を見てますが
**MemAvailable**ってなんなんでしょうか？
使用できる（解放できる）メモリの総合計として見ていいんでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

プログラムに割り当て可能なメモリ量、という理解でよいと思います。

割り当て可能なメモリ、にはファイルキャッシュで利用されているメモリ等も含まれています。
詳しくは [【RHEL】linuxメモリのfreeとmeminfoの関係を図解し利用率の計算方法を説明してみる](http://nopipi.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/09/13/181026) にまとめられている記事を参照すると理解しやすいと思います。